# window.location.href not working when "isset['buttonname']" is occurring (php js)

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, window

As the title says (window.location.href not working when “isset['buttonname']” is occurring (php js)), my page is not redirecting to my new page that I want it to go to. I have tried using :

```
     window.location.href = 'reviewer.php';
    </script>
```

and have also tried using

```
  echo "<script> location.href='http://gwupyterhub.seas.gwu.edu/~rkanungo/clout_computing/reviewer.php'; </script>";
```

Neither one of these scripts are being executed, and I insert them earlier in my code to see if they would even be executed and still nothing, even right after the initial if clause. Any suggestions?

Comment: Without using js and detect where is you problem use header(Location : 'the destination url');

Comment: I'm sorry ,but i do not understand what you mean. Are you suggesting that I use the header command? I have tried that and that also did not work.

Comment: header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

Comment: I have tried that but the page still refreshes and does not go to the desired page.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try the Javascript document ready function with window.location.replace(), for example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {
 window.location.replace("https://example.com");
})();

</script>
```

Alternatively you can only use the window.location.replace() function if the above doesn't work.
The PHP header() function must be called before any actual output, for example "`echo`".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks, I figured it out. Was simply not on the correct url while changing and none of my changes were showing up. Thank you all though!